# How to handle improper session in laravel?

Tags: laravel, session, cookies

[image]laravel 6

hi, i have question for security reason. if in **Browser A**, User login to the website, and i copy their laravel_session value like pic below, then i open **browser B** without login. then i change the value of laravel_session in Browser B with the value from browser A, then i open admin page ex: domain.c om/admin, then it will show admin page as per Browser A. how to prevent scenario like this?? i try

session.php setting

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

'lifetime' => 100,

'expire_on_close' => false,

'encrypt' => false,

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

'table' => 'sessions',

'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

'lottery' => [2, 100],

'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),

'path' => '/',

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

'http_only' => true,

'same_site' => null,
```

Comment: In this scenario you have control over both browser A and browser B.  The "proper" way to deal with this scenario is to secure the browser so unauthorised people can't access the cookie data from the browser. The server can't know if the cookie value coming from potentially an identical browser and IP was the one it sent originally or one that was copied.

Comment: I get what you're asking, but what are you hoping to achieve? Sharing cookie data between 2 separate browsers is usually all up to the end-user(i've done it myself in a couple of scenarios). Every detail you add, like checking ip and agent info is all possible but also circumventable. Only way to truely kick this problem in the teeth is by making people login every 15 mins. We all know how great that is to work with :')

Comment: @Techno is there any way to prevent this happened? i failed in pentest, if i change session: cookie, actually it works, but as far as i know, cookie is not recommend. i try using chaptha,otp, etc, but still can login if i copy the domain_session